# No change in acs 712 readings after connection to load

Tags: arduino-uno

I would like to measure the amount of power used by a 3w bulb. I am using a 9v battery to power the bulb and an acs712 current sensor to get current usage. However, i get no change in values after i connect the load and it light up. 
Is my current sensor faulty or? I'm confused.[image: The image describes how i have set up my connection]

Comment: Which sensitivity of ACS712 do you have? If your bulb is really running at 3W off your 9V battery you will only be pulling about 300mA. A 30A ACS712 won't even notice it. A 5A one might see a little change.

Comment: Can a 20A ACS712 sensor detect the current going through a 12V and 3W light bulb?

Comment: Based on the previous comment it is unlikely that it is sensitive enough.

Comment: The 30Amp version will read 66mV/A, the 20A will read 100mV/A and the 5A version will output 185 mV/A.  So even if the sensor does detect the change in the reading you will see on Analog In will be in the region of 5 to 20, which is less probably less than the noise you see anyway.

Comment: Sensitivity is very low for low wattage load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such light and low-voltage loads you wouldn't normally use a mains rated high current amplifier like this.

Instead you would just use a simple shunt resistor in the low-side of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEbNkH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage dropped across the resistor (and hence the voltage you will read on A0) is proportional to the resistance of the resistor and the current flowing round the circuit.

You want the resistor to be small enough that it doesn't overly affect the operation of the circuit, yet large enough that it drops a voltage you are able to sense at enough resolution.

For example the 1Ω resistor above, with 333mA round the circuit (3W at 9V) would drop (V=IR) `0.3 * 1 = 0.3V`.

While that's not a very high voltage it's small enough to not really affect the circuit, and you can increase the sensitivity of the Arduino by using the 1.1V internal reference instead of relying on the default 5V external Vcc voltage:

```
analogReference(INTERNAL);
```

Or on the Mega2560:

```
analogReference(INTERNAL1V1);
```

Comment: Hi, so what do i use to measure the voltage drop? So that i can feed my Arduino with this data?

Comment: The Arduino. As shown in the circuit.

Comment: What if i use a 220 ohms resistor? 0.333 * 220 = 73.2v (V= I * R) Does that make any sense?

Comment: You will get a lower current with a higher shunt resistor. Shunt resistors need to be ***small enough to not really affect the circuit***

Comment: Ok. So i will then take the voltage from my analog output and then multiply it to the 0.333mA so as to get the power? Forgive me, i am relatively new to electronics stuff

Comment: No, you take the voltage you read using the analog input, divide it by the value of the shunt resistor, and it tells you what the current is. The 0.333 is an example of what it might give you as an answer.

Comment: Ok. So once i have the current, how do i calculate power? I know its I * V but which voltage should i use for power calculation?

Comment: It depends what power you want to calculate. The overall power is the overall voltage (the battery voltage) multiplied by the overall current. The power of just the bulb is the voltage across the bulb (which happens to be the battery voltage minus the voltage you measured across your resistor) multiplied by the current.

Comment: Ok. I have now grasped the concepts well enough. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge and patience. You are a very good teacher :)

Comment: HI, in your circuit, i have seen you've grounded the circuit twice, once to the power source and the second to the arduino board. Is this necessary? Cause i am short on ground pins in my arduino

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/the-importance-of-sharing-grounds/